# Exporting model as fbx applies materials to wrong faces

Tags: materials, color, .fbx

I have a model that when exported as an .fbx from blender, and then imported into blender; the materials seem to move to the wrong faces or just appear different. Any ideas how to fix this?
[image: model]
model

[image: imported .fbx]
imported .fbx to the right, after exporting it as a .fbx

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie There's no textures, or node-based materials

Answer (score 0):

So the problem ended up being that the model was made by joining meshes, and those meshes used the same materials. In the joined models material list, materials were appearing multiple times because of this (although they were the same material). Converting each duplicated material to its own material fixed the problem.

[image]